# Displaying alternative font for @font-face in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Introducing new font in CSS with @font-face as

```
@font-face{
font-family:'myCustom';
font-style:normal;
font-weight:400;
src:local('myCustom'),
local('myCustom-Regular'),
url('myCustom.woff') format('woff')
}
```

and defining the font as

```
font-family: myCustom, Tahoma, Verdana, cursive;
```

However, I have two problems:

1. Until download my custom font, it will not show the second (alternative font), and the text will be blank.
2. If for any reason the visitor browser does not download my custom font, it will not display any text.

How can I display the alternative font until availability of my custom font?

Comment: Are you sure #2 is a real problem?

Comment: @BoltClock: I am not sure about it. I have some reports from the visitors but I could not experience it myself. I guess it happens in older browsers. But I see the first problem myself. Blank text is temporarily for me, and can be permanently for them with the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I expect to happen is that the first available installed font, among those listed in the `font-family` list, will be used. If this does not happen, please post a URL for inspection.

But you may wish to consider the list of font families you use. The odds are that if `Tahoma` and `Verdana` would be acceptable, `cursive` would not be; a normal generic fallback font in this case would be `sans-serif`.

Comment: Heh... that `cursive` made me chuckle. Perhaps Comic Sans would have been more appropriate. It's round and everything.